# Find the number of monic square-free polynomials of degree j over finite field

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, finite-fields

Find the number of monic square-free polynomials of degree j >=1 over the finite field GF(q) ?

I have no idea how to approach this. I was thinking if there was a way to write a monic polynomial uniquely, it might lead to something. 
Could someone help with this

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan has given [a complete nice answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93553/11619) to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If monic polynomial $p(x)$ is **not** square-free, it can be written uniquely as $a(x) b(x)^2$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are monic, $a(x)$ is square-free and $b(x)$ has degree $\ge 1$.  Considering the possible degrees of $b(x)$, you should be able to derive a recurrence, an equation for the number of square-free polynomials of degree $d$ in terms of the numbers with lower degrees.

You might also look up ["squarefree polynomials"](https://oeis.org/search?q=%22squarefree+polynomials%22&sort=&language=&go=Search) in the OEIS to get the answers for some values of $q$.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation on why it could be written uniquely. Then how to approach. I am new to abstract algebra.

Comment: Use the unique factorization into monic irreducibles.  
$a(x)$ is the product of the factors that occur to odd powers, $b(x)$ is the (monic) square root of $p(x)/a(x)$.